# Load Javascript balise in html file with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I'm looking to make an HTML file loading system (via XMLHttpRequest) with in my html file  tags.

I don't know if it is possible, or at least to get the "js" and load them. All of this, while necessarily leaving the  in the outer .html file.

I don't want any  or anything like that.

Thanks

I tried an eval() and
`document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = oReq.responseText;`

However, the rendering doesn't work.

Here is the rendering of the actual code:

```
function view(current_url, div) {
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open("GET", current_url, true);
  oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
    //console.log(oReq);
    console.log(oReq.status);
    //console.log(oReq.responseText);
    if (oReq.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = oReq.responseText;
      eval(oReq.responseText);

      var script = document.createElement('script'),
      src = URL.createObjectURL(oReq.response);

      script.src = src;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    } else {
      document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = "Dev-Time Framework v "+devtime_version()+". Error" + oReq.status+"";
    }
  };
  oReq.send();
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to fetch a remote `*.js` file, and load its code as if it were a part of your page?

Comment: yes @FiddlingAway (file in my website) not other website (eg: site.com/assets/js/main.js the file)

Comment: So you don't want to do something like `<script src="https://example.com/example.js></script>`, just make it look like the code is in a file on your website?

Comment: yes, in the "https://example.com/footer.html" per exemple, (footer.html content just the footer and scripts

for the "header.html with css and <meta> it's good, i don't have problem for the other balise.

Comment: I do everything in html/js to create a "framework" so to speak. without php

Answer (score 0):

You could try and do it like this.

```
function view(current_url, div) {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.responseType = "text";   // <=== you need this part
    oReq.open("GET", current_url, true);
    oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
        // we'll comment out all of these console.logs
        //console.log(oReq);
        //console.log(oReq.status);
        //console.log(oReq.responseText);
        if (oReq.status == 200) {
            // you don't need these, as well, unless there's a
            // reason for you to actually display the contents
            // of the loaded script. And you don't need to use eval
            //document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = oReq.responseText;
            //eval(oReq.responseText);
            
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            // we'll set the source differently, by using current_url
            // src = URL.createObjectURL(oReq.response);
            script.src = current_url;
            script.textContent = oReq.response;
            script.onload = myCallback; // you need this if you want to
            // execute parts of your code based on what was loaded from
            // the provided link

            document.body.appendChild(script);
            
        } else {
            document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = "Dev-Time Framework v "+devtime_version()+". Error" + oReq.status+"";
        }
    };
    oReq.send();
}

// this is called in our script.onload part within the view(...) function
function myCallback() {
    // do stuff
}
```

Now, let's say that, for whatever reason, I want to load jQuery as a result of an XHR call. By doing what I've written above, I can make something like this (run the snippet to see it in action).

```js
function view(current_url, div) {
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.responseType = "text";
  oReq.open("GET", current_url, true);
  oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
    if (oReq.status == 200) {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = current_url;
      script.textContent = oReq.response;
      script.onload = myCallback;

      document.body.appendChild(script);
    } else {
      document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = "Dev-Time Framework v "+devtime_version()+". Error" + oReq.status+"";
    }
  };
  oReq.send();
}

function myCallback() {
  jQuery("#main").addClass("normal");
  alert("hooray!");
}

  var current_url = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js";
  var div = "main";
  view(current_url,div);
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#main.normal {
  background-color: red;
  border: 5px dashed blue;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">Lorem ipsum sit tolor amet</div>
```

Comment: I didn't ask for this. I asked that when I xmlhttprequest an html, the JS in it should load.

Eg:

index.html

```<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
<script type="module">
  import { view, site_url } from './models/devtime.js?t=00009'; // Or the extension could be just `.js`
  document.title = "Accueil - Mateo M.";
  view(site_url()+'views/layouts/header.html', "header");
  view(site_url()+'views/index/index.html', "content");
  view(site_url()+'views/layouts/footer.html', "footer");
</script>``` 
In footer, i have "<script...>" files

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your initial problem. So you want to embed the entire response of your XHR into your page, not JS files, but everything? And then make it behave as it does on its original website?

Comment: Yes, like a <?php require file; ?> or <?php include('file.php'); ?> containing <script>. But without going through PHP necessarily

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done in a reliable way (unless you also control the site you're fetching the content from). You would have to have a good way of parsing the data you fetched, in order to accurately separate CSS, JS and HTML, and place them in DOM nodes you'd have to create on the site that's doing the fetching. Maybe [some of these](https://openbase.com/categories/js/best-javascript-html-parser-libraries?vs=parse5%2Ccheerio%2Chtmlparser2) would work for you. Wish I could help more than this.

Comment: I would look, because well, if you look at the JS frameworks do that well. Reading "view()" with <script> at the footer like a classic site (like my code above with a header; content; footer)